# Unmanaged DLL is not loading with DLLImport C#

Tags: c#, dll

I must be missing something here; going crazy.. I'm using VS2010 C#, developing a Windows Form application in C#.  In the same solution I have a c++ dll project that outputs it's DLL to the same "/bin/" folder as the C# executable.  I'm looking at the folder and the file is definitely there.  I even used the following to make sure it existed at run-time:

```
// yep.. it's there...
string s = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Foo.dll";
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(System.IO.File.Exists(s));
```

my DLL has this:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int test_func();
```

which I confirmed with a DLL explorer utility to have the correct name inside.  The function itself does nothing but "return 4;"

C# code is:

```
[DllImport("Foo.dll")]
private static extern int test_func();
```

I get this error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in .exe

Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'Foo.dll': Invalid access to memory location. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703E6)

Comment: is your app...32bit or 64bit?

Comment: 32bit.  Or I should say I'm not explicitly defining a 64bit application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is occurring when the framework calls `LoadLibrary`. That can be deduced from the error message:

> Unable to load DLL 'Foo.dll'

The error code that is reported is a COM error code that wraps Win32 error code 998, aka [`ERROR_NOACCESS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681388.aspx#ERROR_NOACCESS). The scenario that leads to a call to `LoadLibrary` throwing `ERROR_NOACCESS` is described here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196069

> **SYMPTOMS**
>
> The LoadLibrary() API may sometimes encounter an access violation
>   while attempting to map a specified module into the address space of
>   the calling process. In this event, LoadLibrary() returns a value of
>   NULL and GetLastError() returns an error code of 998 (ERROR_NOACCESS).
>   Back to the top | Give Feedback
>
> **CAUSE**
>
> The Windows NT status code STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION is mapped to the
>   Win32 error code ERROR_NOACCESS. As a result, if the operating system
>   loader encounters an access violation (exception C0000005) while
>   mapping the specified DLL file image or executing the startup code,
>   the loader will set the last error to 998 (ERROR_NOACCESS) and the
>   LoadLibrary() function will fail with a return value of NULL. Back to
>   the top | Give Feedback
>
> **MORE INFORMATION**
>
> When an access violation occurs anywhere in the startup code, the
>   exception dispatcher detects whether the process that encountered this
>   exception is being debugged. If so, this first chance exception is
>   sent to the debugger.
>
> To troubleshoot the LoadLibrary() failure, run the application under a
>   debugger and enable first chance exception handling for the C0000005
>   Access Violation exception. If an access violation occurs when the
>   LoadLibrary() function is called, the application will break into the
>   debugger. The debugger's call stack can then be used to trace where
>   the exception occurred. The stack trace should help you narrow down
>   the actual problem related to the exception being encountered.
>
> For information on how to enable first chance exception handling for
>   the C0000005 Access violation exception, please refer to the debugger
>   documentation.

In essence, your DLL is producing an access violation in its startup code. Many things could cause that and you'll need to do some debugging of the DLL. I suggest that you attempt to debug this from a native C++ host. It will likely be easier to debug the DLL that way.

As an aside, your function uses the `cdecl` calling convention, and once you get past the current hurdle, you'll need to modify your C# p/invoke to specify `CallingConvention.Cdecl`.

Comment: I used DllImport[] on LoadLibrary from within my C# application and call it returned "0". ?!?  I used the exact same path that I used with File.Exists() so I think this must be some kind of permissions problem..

Comment: No. It returns `LoadLibrary` returns `0` when it fails. That indicates an error. If you include `SetLastError=true` in the `LoadLibrary` pinvoke you can call `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` and it will return 998. It's not permissions. Your DLL's `DllMain` is raising an access violation. Your next step is to do exactly what I said. Debug this with a native host. Or work out how to enable unmanaged debugging from your C# host.

Comment: Oh man I did not see this one coming...  a global static class was accessing it's own "static std::map<>" member.  But it appears that it was being accessed before the the member's definition.  I guess it somehow had not initialized it's own values in time to be used by the constructor.  I didn't even think that was possible!  I reordered the code and now it works.. crazy.

Comment: Yes. Static initialization. Catches you out!!

Answer (score 0):

Assume you already saw [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327096/win-7-dllimport-c-sharp-odd-error-invalid-access-to-memory-location).

Have you opened "foo.dll" with [depends.exe](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to ensure you have all the dependencies satisfied?

Comment: The DLL is doing nothing.  It depends only on a couple stl template headers.  I ran depends.exe and only got this:

   Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
   Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.

I'm guessing it's complaining because the DLL is 32bit and I'm running Windows 7 x64.