# "Unable to load DLL ..... Invalid access to memory location" error

Tags: c#

I am using a third party .dll ([from this website](http://www.soft.tahionic.com/)) which generates Hardware ID. I am using it as per the [direction](http://www.soft.tahionic.com/download-hdd_id/hardware%20id%20programming%20source%20code/how%20to%20call%20it.html#dotnet_C#) provided on that site.

```
    [DllImport("HardwareIDExtractorC.dll")]
    public static extern String GetIDESerialNumber(byte DriveNumber);

    private void btnGetHardwareId_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(GetIDESerialNumber(0));
    }
```

But it is raising the following error-

Unable to load DLL 'HardwareIDExtractorC.dll': Invalid access to memory location. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703E6)

Am i missing anything here?

Comment: In which type of application you are doing this?

Comment: C# Windows application. Framework 3.5, Visual studio 2008.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284/windows-vista-unable-to-load-dll-x-dll-invalid-access-to-memory-location-d
It may be the UAC problem